# How to use Async/Await or Promise in reducer function so that when i initialized my initial state (through axios) , the reducer func. should wait

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

in the reducer function, I want to initialize the initialState which is first updated by some data through an API call (by Axios) then it will pass through the reducer function.

The problem is when it is being updated by through an API call, the reducer has not taken the updated state, which I came to realize when I access the initialState in a different component, that will show me the very first initialization.

**Initial State**

```
    var seriesData = {
        horror:[],
        comedi:[],
        romantic:[]
    }
```

**API call through AXIOS and try to update the initial state**

```
    var gen_typ = ['horror','comedi','romantic']
    
    gen_typ.forEach(elm => {
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SD_API}${elm}`)
        .then((result) => {
            seriesData = {...seriesData,elm:result}
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

**Reducer function**

```
    export function SD_Operation(state = seriesData,action){
        switch(action.type){
    
            case "GET_MORE":
               return{
               ...state,
              [action.payload.genTyp]:[...state[action.payload.genTyp],action.payload.data]}
            
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

**when I access the initial state in one of my components and console out**

**inside component**

```
    var Series_data = useSelector(state => state.SD_Operation);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('@login page',Series_data) ;
    },[])
```

**output I get**

@login page
{horror: Array(0), comedi: Array(0), romantic: Array(0)}

```
comedi: []
horror: []
romantic: []
```

**output I expect**

**an array of data**

{horror: Array(some length), comedi: Array(some length), romantic: Array(some length)}

```
comedi: [{},{}....]
horror: [{},{}....]
romantic: [{},{}....]
```

Comment: You need to delay the entire store creation if you need to run async stuff before initializing the reducer, afaik it's not recommended. See answer below. What you're trying isn't impossible but there isn't much benefit to forcing it this way. Consider adding the initial state on the server side (bootstrapped into the js bundle) if it really must be there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical scenario, and commonly solved differently:

1. The initial state for your reducer is simply empty. The data is not there yet when the app loads, so define it accordingly.
2. Create an async action (using thunk or other middleware) that fetches the API data.
3. Dispatch this action when your root component mounts (in `componentDidMount` or via a `useEffect` with empty dep. array).
4. Any other selectors and components using this API data needs to take the initial empty state into account.